# Applet cannot seem to find resources

Tags: java, applet

There is a similar question ([Java Applet Cannot Locate Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460693/java-applet-cannot-locate-resources)), but `base` gives me an error, and asks me for the creation of a variable.

---

I have an applet that I embedded into HTML with:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="600" width="800">
<param name="code" value="net.me.applet.WindowMain" />
</object>
```

The applet launches, and attempting to change the contentpane's color works too, so that means that the link with the HTML might not have errors.

Then, I linked my assets like so:

```
ImageIcon left = new ImageIcon(getCodeBase(), "Arrow_Left.png");
```

The PNG is in the same directory as my applet. The images don't show, so I assume that the assets were not found. I also tried doing `"/Arrow_Left.png"`, without avail.

The directory structure is this:

```
/ root directory
index.html
(dir)net
     | me
         | applet
               | WindowMain.class
```

---

When I developed the applet in Eclipse, I made a package with the compilation unit, and a folder called "assets" in the src folder, and I accessed those for testing purposes with `ImageIcon("src/assets/Arrow_Left.png")`

Comment: You should never access resources using src, as it won't exist at runtime

Comment: *"The PNG is in the same directory as my applet"* is that the same directory as your index.html file or your class file (in the package)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have my index.html in the root directory, and then there is a series of directories as packages, so from root directory: net > me > applet > WindowMain.class. I put the PNG in the same dir as my WindowMain.class

Comment: You should also beware that applets are effectively deprecated as the plugin is no longer supported (and is effectively blocked by most browsers)

Comment: Use getClass().getResource("Arrow_Left.png") instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer I will keep that in mind, but I would like to finish what I started as it is for now. I got firefox to launch the applet, but I had to do changes with javacpl to enable `file:///`. As stated, changing contentpane color worked in the browser, so the applet is probably loaded properly.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I also put `ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Arrow_Left.png"))`, but that did not work.

Comment: Start using ImageIO.read instead of ImageIcon, it will grow an IOException when it fails to read the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I put the PNG in the same dir as my WindowMain.class

Then the string needs to be the relative path from the code base. Something like:

```
ImageIcon left = new ImageIcon(getCodeBase(), "net/me/applet/Arrow_Left.png");
```

But definitely heed the advice to use `ImageIO.read(..)` which provides better feed-back.

Comment: I think it is a position issue, as I made a label to test and it is not there either